# Oracle FLOAT equivalent in Redshift

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I'm moving my data from Oracle to Redshift.

What is the best option for Oracle FLOAT data type in Redshift.

The column data type that I have is FLOAT(64).

Comment: If you need greater precision you may consider using varchar to store your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html

`FLOAT` is 8 bytes, which is 64 bits...